# Change timeout for Parse requests

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

In the iOS Developers Guide for Parse, it states "By default, all connections have a timeout of 10 seconds." I am looking to change this for all requests made from the app, but am not finding any information on how to do so.

The reason we'd like to modify this is that it's taking a long time for requests to fail when the user doesn't have Wi-Fi or Cellular enabled. We want to reduce the amount of time it takes to receive said error message, just a little. We don't want to implement our own reachability tests, as it will result in duplicate popup error messages and we have many requests in various view controllers throughout the app.

Can the timeout be modified, or is there some other way to obtain a better user experience than waiting 10 seconds for an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no information on this but certainly the request timeout limits are set by Parse and a developer will not be able to change them. I think they kept the timeouts to be long to avoid a user request being rejected if their connection becomes suddenly intermittent or they go in a tunnel, etc.
You can try to warp Parse queries around a timer which uses let say 5 seconds timeout, if the response does not come in that time you cancel your your query using PFQuery `cancel` function and show them a message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid timing out, consider checking Reachability before making the call. You may want to show the user an alert if they're not connected and you need to do something.

A lot of people say you should just assume a connection and make the attempt without checking reachability; basically just let the connection fail and handle the error that way. I think as long as the failure isn't invisible to the user, so they don't blame your app vs their network you're good though.